# BIG_query_delete_column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata, sql-delete

How can I delete  columns in one table  which name are coming from other table ?

Comment: Please provide an example of data input and your expected result.  See the following on best practices for asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.